# Display a ul horizontally but li vertically rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have an app where I am trying to show the featured posts on the homepage.  I want the posts to show up horizontally but all the items of the post (the image, the title and the text) to be vertical.

For the CSS I have:

```
#hentry ul{
  list-style: none;
}

#hentry li{
  display: inline;
}
```

And on the homepage I have:

```
<div id="hentry">

 <ul>
  <% @featured_posts.each do |post| %>
     <li><%= image_tag post.featured_image.url.to_s %></li>
     <li><%= post.title %></li>
     <li><%= post.text %></li>

  <% end %>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Currently the posts show up in a horizontal line but it goes

```
image 1, title 1, text 1, image 2, title 2, text 2, image 3,  title 3, text 3
```

instead i want

```
image 1    image 2   image 3
title 1    title 2   title 3
 text 1     text 2    text 3
```

I was thinking maybe adding classes to the li tag might be a solution but I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: You want to make it look like a table without a table tag, I'm afraid that's not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the flex model can help:**

```css
ul {
  display:flex;/* this is enough */
}
li {
  display:block;/* kills the list-item */
  margin:5px;
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50&text=image_1"/>
    <h1>title 1</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
</li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50&text=image_2"/>
    <h1>title 2</h1>
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
</li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50&text=image_3"/>
    <h1>title 3</h1>
    <p>paragraph 3</p>
</li>
```

**or display:table:**

```css
ul {
  display:table;
  border-spacing:10px 5px ;
}
li {
  display:table-cell;
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50&text=image_1"/>
    <h1>title 1</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
</li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50&text=image_2"/>
    <h1>title 2</h1>
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
</li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50&text=image_3"/>
    <h1>title 3</h1>
    <p>paragraph 3</p>
</li>
```

Comment: This works great.  I changed my <li> tags so there is only one around image, title and text instead of an <li> around each.  Then I just needed to do some minor spacing/styling changes.  Thanks!